Error when loading a pre-trained json model
ive been trying to execute a project where i had to use the architecture of my trained model (i stored in a json file )but im getting the error that ive mentioned below
Here's the error I'm getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Richard.Joy\Desktop\Final-antispoofing_models\anti.py", line 14, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Richard.Joy\Desktop\Final-antispoofing_models\antispoof_env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 575, in model_from_json
    return serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Richard.Joy\Desktop\Final-antispoofing_models\antispoof_env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\serialization_lib.py", line 694, in deserialize_keras_object
    cls = _retrieve_class_or_fn(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Richard.Joy\Desktop\Final-antispoofing_models\antispoof_env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\serialization_lib.py", line 812, in _retrieve_class_or_fn
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Could not locate class 'Functional'. Make sure custom classes are decorated with `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()`. Full object config: {'class_name': 'Functional', 'config':.....(**contents of the json file**........'keras_version': '2.15.0', 'backend': 'tensorflow')

Here are the library versions(on vscode):
keras                   3.3.3
opencv-python           4.9.0.80
tensorflow              2.16.1
python                  3.12.3

Here are the library versions(on google colab where i trained my model):
keras                   3.3.3
opencv-python           4.8.0.76
tensorflow              2.15.0

Here's my code:
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array 
import os
import numpy as np

root_dir = os.getcwd()
# Load Face Detection Model
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# Load Anti-Spoofing Model graph
json_file = open('C:/Users/Richard.Joy/Desktop/Final-antispoofing_models/Antispoofing_model_mobilenet.json','r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load antispoofing model weights 
model.load_weights('C:/Users/Richard.Joy/Desktop/Final-antispoofing_models/project_antispoofing_model_97-0.957895.h5')
print("Model loaded from disk")

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    try:
        ret,frame = video.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:  
            face = frame[y-5:y+h+5,x-5:x+w+5]
            resized_face = cv2.resize(face,(160,160))
            resized_face = resized_face.astype("float") / 255.0
            resized_face = np.expand_dims(resized_face, axis=0)
            # pass the face ROI through the trained liveness detector
            # model to determine if the face is "real" or "fake"
            preds = model.predict(resized_face)[0]
            print(preds)
            if preds> 0.5:
                label = 'poof'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                    (0, 0, 255), 2)
            else:
                label = 'eal'
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (x,y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h),
                (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
    except Exception as e: 
        pass
video.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

What am I supposed to do? I tried to downgrade the libraries but was getting error in that too.

Did you try this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22644#issuecomment-1555252717 ?

now the [ERROR:0@5.030] is gone but other issues still persist

As no one has answered yet you can edit your current question and show your current issues or you can create a new question. Please ask only one question in one post.

(As an aside, the root_dir variable is doubly useless; you are not using it, and you don't need to know which directory you are in. See also What exactly is current working directory?)

i removed root_dir but still getting this issue
